# What does the notation $f(x^-)=l$ mean?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, notation

What does the notation $f(x^-)=l$ mean? The context in which it appears is:

> Let $f: [a,b] \to \mathbb{R} $ be a monotonic function and $x \in (a,b]$.    Show that
>    if there is a sequence $\{x_n\} \subset (a,b]$ such that $x_n < x \
>  \forall n \in \mathbb{N},\ \lim_{n \to \infty } x_n = x $ and $\lim_{n
>  \to \infty} f(x_n)=l$ then $\mathbf{f(x^-)=l}$.

Comment: "limit from the left" : If we approach $x$ with values less than $x$, then $f(x)$ tends to $l$.

Comment: $f(x^-)$ looks like a sometimes used notation for $\lim_{t\to x^-}f(t)$ or $\lim_{h\to 0,h>0}f(x-h)$

Comment: Thank you, now it makes sense!

Answer (score 1):

$f(x^-)$ stands for $\lim_{t\to x^-} f(t)$, which is $\sup_{t<x} f(t)$ for weakly increasing functions and it is $\inf_{t<x} f(t)$ for weakly decreasing functions.